# R focal weights from probability density function

Tags: r, probability-density, r-raster

I am trying to build a spatial grid ("window") containing the weights from a pre-defined prob. density function. Currently there is a raster package function called `focalWeight()` but the only options are 'circle', 'Gauss' or 'rectangle'. I would like to create one using, for example, the Cauchy distribution. Any suggestions on how to do that?